# WebView displays a blank view for certain links

Tags: android, webview

I'm using a webview:

```
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    loading.show();
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
            });
```

For most links, it works just fine. But for, http://m.stubhub.com (and any of the same domain), it only shows a blank view (though it's finished loading the page). Are there settings, I'm missing or something?

Btw, there aren't any errors, as far as I can tell.

Suggestions/advice greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried *onReceivedSslError* ? :

```
 public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
     handler.proceed() ;
}
```

Let me know if that helps !

Comment: Yes, I have. There weren't any errors as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the permissions the site required. It uses HTML5 storage, so permission for DOMStorage had to be enabled...

`webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

Comment: like this `webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);` ? how did you know that is uses that ?

Comment: I enabled all the permissions and looked for the one that made it work via binary search.